# Sass fonts family

Tags: fonts, sass, font-face

im new to sass and i have questions about the font-face thing.

1- I saw this some here, does this work for example? or each type need the correct extencion?

2- Does google font really only offers .ttf ? Or there is an "hidden" option to get the rest?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: $font-weight-light;
    src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('opentype'), /* IE9+ Compat Modes */
         url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('woff2'), /* Super modern browsers */
         url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('woff'), /* Modern browsers */
         url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Are you getting Roboto from google? If so, you dont use font face in this manner. You link to google per the link they give you and then use font family: roboto

Comment: To answer your first question, yes the font should have the corrct extension like this. url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern browsers */ . You can look up FontSquirrel and they generate the correct fonts if you only have one kind such as TFF